# How to limit visible option in dropdown using ngOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ngOptions for my dropdown. Since my dropdown has a lot of options, I want to limit the visible items in the dropdown to 5. User should be able to scroll to the rest of the options.

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="model.year" ng-options="year for year in model.yearOptions"></select>
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.yearOptions = ["2017","2018","2019","2020","2021", "....","2050"];
$scope.model.year = "2017";
```

This is not to be confused with size/ng-size which expands the height of the original box itself.

[image]

Comment: see this example maybe it help you https://jsfiddle.net/88cxzhom/27/

Comment: Can you explain how's that not html's select 'size' property? Size does exactly the thing you are asking - so size = "5" would show 5 elements and you would be able to scroll to others. Try posting some code on plnkr fiddle or somewhere so we get better idea.

Comment: @FerhadOthman Thanks, your example is good but it expands the existing div and the items below move down. I want to limit the visible options in the scroll. Please see added image.

Comment: I suggest looking for [angular-chosen](https://github.com/leocaseiro/angular-chosen) plugins, or use simply dropdown list like bootstrap then you can use infinti scroll to load more data

Comment: I can make a example for you if you need

Answer (score 0):

You can style the select options, but it's not easy or consistent across browsers. Here's a good article on the subject: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms#Dealing_with_the_select_nightmare

Try giving your select tag a [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) and [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property.

Example: `<select class="myClassName" ng-option="..."></select>`
...
`.myClassName { height: 5em; overflow: auto;}`

Answer (score 0):

try to use `limitTo` filter:

```
<select ng-model="model.year" 
        ng-options="year for year in model.yearOptions | limitTo : 5"></select>
```

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/65l35x?p=preview

Comment: limitTo makes the rest of the options inaccessible. I want the user to be able to access those using scroll.

Answer (score 0):

try adding size="5"

```
<select size="5" ng-model="model.year" ng-options="year for year in model.yearOptions"></select>
```